# mongodb 2.6.5 replica set with authentication

Tags: mongodb

all, I configured replica set without authentication has no issues.

I used the following command to install on 3 VM.
    mongod --install --replSet "MSWrs" --verbose -vvvvv --logpath c:/logs/mongo-server.log

in mongodb shell

```
 var democonfig=
{_id: "MSWrs", members:
[{_id:0,host: 'xxxxx1.cloudapp.net:27017',priority:10}, 

{_id:1,host:'xxxxx2.cloudapp.net:27017'},

{_id:2,host:'xxxxx3.cloudapp.net:27017',arbiterOnly:true}]};
```

then initiate

```
 rs.initiate(democonfig)
```

it successfully initiated. And worked fine.

But I need to add authentication, so I added admin user account to admin db for primary, secondary and arbiter.

I added user to each using:

```
use admin
db.addUser("admin","password")

then re-install service with --auth

mongod --auth --install --replSet "MSWrs" --verbose -vvvvv --logpath c:/logs/mongo-server.log
```

after started services, both primary and secondary says rs.Secondary the arbiter says rs.RECOVERING as shown below, any idea where was done wrong? I read some where saying I can use [security key file](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.keyFile) and another place saying [not really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052930/mongodb-sharding-replica-sets-with-authentication-via-keyfile). Any one knows how to use security key file or what extra steps that I need to do to get the replica set to work? I can connect to all of them using Robomongo fine with authentication, just replica set would not show primary. Please help.

Comment: I could not post pictures since my reputation is under 10.

Comment: you need to use a keyfile as per http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#inter-process-auth  - the "not really" link is about version 2.0 which was years ago.

Comment: I am using Windows environment,  any idea how to generate key file in Windows,  Windows has openssl?

Comment: I figured out key file, it is just a text file with keys inside.

Comment: right, and now you follow steps here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-auth/#procedure

Comment: btw, you probably want to remove all those vvvvv's since you are likely to fill your disk with the logs at such high level of verbose.